# shiro.ini configuration failing after maven dependency upgrades/changes

Tags: java, apache, maven, jboss, shiro

> Error from jboss startup when deploying an **ear** file:

```
sob_backend          |  ... 40 more
sob_backend          | 
sob_backend          | 09:44:46,667 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/sob-handler-web]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 98) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener: org.apache.shiro.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to set property 'sessionManager.sessionDAO' with value [se.cehis.efsob.web.authorization.shiro.CustomShiroSessionDAO@cc7e7ac] on object of type org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager.  If 'se.cehis.efsob.web.authorization.shiro.CustomShiroSessionDAO@cc7e7ac' is a reference to another (previously defined) object, prefix it with '$' to indicate that the referenced object should be used as the actual value.  For example, $se.cehis.efsob.web.authorization.shiro.CustomShiroSessionDAO@cc7e7ac
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.setProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:659) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:608) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:720) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applySingleProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:364) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.applyProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:325) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$AssignmentStatement.doExecute(ReflectionBuilder.java:955) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$Statement.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:887) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder$BeanConfigurationProcessor.execute(ReflectionBuilder.java:765) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.buildObjects(ReflectionBuilder.java:260) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.buildInstances(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:167) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:130) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createSecurityManager(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:108) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:94) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.IniSecurityManagerFactory.createInstance(IniSecurityManagerFactory.java:46) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.IniFactorySupport.createInstance(IniFactorySupport.java:123) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.util.AbstractFactory.getInstance(AbstractFactory.java:47) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.createWebSecurityManager(IniWebEnvironment.java:203) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.configure(IniWebEnvironment.java:99) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.web.env.IniWebEnvironment.init(IniWebEnvironment.java:92) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:45) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.util.LifecycleUtils.init(LifecycleUtils.java:40) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.createEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:221) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader.initEnvironment(EnvironmentLoader.java:133) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener.contextInitialized(EnvironmentLoaderListener.java:58) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
sob_backend          |  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
sob_backend          |  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
sob_backend          |  at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
sob_backend          |  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
sob_backend          |  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
sob_backend          |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
sob_backend          |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
sob_backend          |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]
sob_backend          |  at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
sob_backend          | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.setSessionDAO on bean class 'class org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager' - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "se.cehis.efsob.web.authorization.shiro.CustomShiroSessionDAO" but expected signature "org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.SessionDAO"
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2235) [commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:1.8.3]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2151) [commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:1.8.3]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1957) [commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:1.8.3]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.setProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2064) [commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:1.8.3]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:1017) [commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:1.8.3]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:456) [commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar:1.8.3]
sob_backend          |  at org.apache.shiro.config.ReflectionBuilder.setProperty(ReflectionBuilder.java:651) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
```

> Relevant line:

```
Cannot invoke org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.DefaultSessionManager.setSessionDAO on bean class 'class org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager' - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "se.cehis.efsob.web.authorization.shiro.CustomShiroSessionDAO" but expected signature "org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.SessionDAO"
```

> shiro.ini configuration file:

```
[main]

sessionManager = org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
;cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
cacheManager = se.cehis.sob.cache.EfsobCacheManager
sessionDAO = se.cehis.efsob.web.authorization.shiro.CustomShiroSessionDAO

securityManager.sessionManager = $sessionManager
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.name = e_session_id
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.path = /
;securityManager.sessionManager.sessionIdCookie.secure = true
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager
securityManager.sessionManager.sessionDAO = $sessionDAO

;jdbcRealm=se.cehis.efsob.common.security.JdbcRealmImpl
jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT ID FROM ACL_USER WHERE ID = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = SELECT ROLE_NAME FROM ACL_ROLES where USER_ID = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = SELECT PERMISSION_NAME FROM ACL_PERMISSION WHERE ROLE_NAME = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 

ds = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
ds.resourceName = java:jboss/datasources/efobDS
jdbcRealm.dataSource= $ds
```

I've tried to upgrade the shiro maven version to 1.4.0 but I believe the same error still occurring.

Anyone that can shed some light on this?

Comment: What is the class hierarchy of `CustomShiroSessionDAO` ?